# Angular email validator throws away keystrokes

Tags: angularjs, breeze

In the following code, if I leave in the email tag, my keystrokes get thrown away as invalid - what is going on? I can paste in a valid email, but trying to type directly, the keystroke gets thrown away and the textbox is flagged invalid.

```
<input type="email" ng-model="vm.application.contact.emailAddress" class="form-control" required placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" >
```

If I remove the type, I'm ok. Is there a config setting to prevent validation on keypress?

I get the same behavior if I use the type="number"

Comment: your field is validating or not? There are two valid formats: test@gmail and test@gmail.com, i.e., if you use only "@", there should be one or more characters before and after it and if you use both "@" and ".", ther eshould be one or more characters before and after "." and "@"

Comment: Angular is not doing that. Do you have another library or plugin that could do that? Which browser, on which platform? Can you reproduce in in a plunkr?

Comment: It seems to be an issue in chrome and in Safari. Works as expected in IE and Firefox.

Comment: so what happens when you change the `name="email"` to say `name="input"` ? see this [angularjs docs example of input-email-validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) and see this [jsfiddle to compare your input attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/1h8d3pe2/) vs the angularjs docs example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems Angular and Breeze.js are both in competition to validate the model. Taking the attribute on the model on the db side solved. it - see above.

Answer (score 0):

As I dig further into this, I think the issue has to do with the fact that I am using Breeze and there seems to be a Angular v Breeze smackdown happening.

If I add a temp variable (vm.email) the input type="email" is now an editable control.

Also, it seems Breeze/Angular has a disagreement if using type="number" when the db type is a string. switching to type="tel" solves this problem and brings up the numbers on a phone, while still keeping the backing type as string - which is required for Zip/Postal code: otherwise, ZIP of 02188 would be 2188 when stored in a db...

Comment: so it sounds like  `@JB Nizet` was right in his comment =)

Comment: I agree! @JB Nizet was correct and thanks for following up  Shehryar Abbas